# Move ImageView through onTouch()

Tags: android

I've a `AbsoluteLayout` and I wanna move my `ImageView` around this Layout trough my touch points , Look at my code , Everything is fine when I touch any points, Points are saved in a variable , but `ImageView` was disappear , Any Ideas?

My XML Layout :

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/FirstBall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="59dp"
        android:layout_y="446dp"
        android:src="@drawable/redball" />

</AbsoluteLayout>
```

My Codes:

```
FstBall=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.FirstBall);
FstBall.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();
    int action = event.getAction();
    float FnlResX = 0;
    float FnlResY = 0;
    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
    FnlResX = x;
    FnlResY = y;
    int tst1 = (int) FnlResX;
    int tst2= (int) FnlResY;
    FstBall.scrollBy(tst1, tst2);
    }
    return true;
    }
    });
```

Comment: http://iserveandroid.blogspot.com/2011/01/dragmove-image-in-custom-view-part-i.html

Answer (score 1):

That's a behavior to be expected, given that you just scroll the window instead of actually moving the view. The right way will be to override the onTouchEvent method of your layout.

```
public class MyAbsoluteLayout extends AbsoluteLayout{

   private static final String TAG = MyAbsoluteLayout.class.getSimpleName();

   private int mDepth;

   @Override
   public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
        final View child = getChildAt(mDepth);
        if(child == null){
            Log.e(TAG, "no child at selected depth");
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
        final ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams)   child.getLayoutParams();
        params.leftMargin = event.getX();
        params.topMargin = event.getY();
        child.setLayoutParams(params);
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    public void setMovingChildDepth(final int depth){
       mDepth = depth;
    }
}

public class MyActivity extends Activity{

    public void onCreate(Bundle data){
        super.onCreate(data);

        final MyAbsoluteLayout layout = new MyAbsoluteLayout(this);
        final ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams layoutParams = new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(FILL_PARENT,FILL_PARENT);
        layout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
        final ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams viewParams = new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(100,100);
        params.leftMargin = 100;
        params.topMargin = 100;
        imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(yourDrawable);
        layout.addView(imageView,params);

        layout.setMovingChildDepth(layout.indexOfChild(imageView));

        setContentView(layout);
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the error? In order to implement this you shoud create your own class that extends AbsoluteLayout and override its onTouch method

Comment: We must implement onTouch() or onTouchEvent() ?! because onTouch methods need an object to implementation.

Comment: Yes, should be onTouchEvent, but you should implement onTouchEvent of the absolute layout. The implementation you provided below is correct in case it is in the representing you AbsoluteLayout - i.e `public class MyAbsoluteLayout extends AbsoluteLayout{ ... onTouchEvent ...}`

Comment: I've edited my answer. The provided implementation should work, although I haven't really tested it as i don't have a testing device and the emulator will take too much time to load.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5739/discussion-between-mr-james-and-ilate)

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
super.onTouchEvent(event);
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams params = new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(FstBall.getLayoutParams());
params.x = (int) event.getX();
params.y = (int) event.getY();
FstBall.setLayoutParams(params);
return true;
}
```